# How to add and display the suffix m² to a SharePoint number column in Powerapps

Tags: forms, sharepoint, formatting, powerapps, suffix

In a SharePoint list one column is declared as numeric, and with SharePoint's own "suffix adding tool" I assigned **m²** to the column value. The input **1000** is then correctly displayed in the list view as **1000 m²**.

But in the Powerapps customized form with this list as source, same DataCardValue is displayed only as *1000*, without displaying *m²*.

DataCardValue default Format-Setting is =>  *TextFormat.Number*

...and I have already tried several things with it to display *1000 m²*, none works:

```
TextFormat.Number & "m²"
Parent.Default, "m²"
Text(Parent.Default, "m²")
DataCardValue3.Text & "m²"
```

Does anyone have a solution for this **(without having to add an additional label)**? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a label on top of the input. Then conditionally show/hide the label based on the formMode. Users wouldn't see the "m²" when entering data into the form (aka form in edit mode), but they would see the "m²" when the form is in view mode.

[image]

Changing the format from number to text will allow you to do it, if that's an option.

[image]

You can also use the column formatting in SP list to add the suffix:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "='@currentField' + 'm²'"
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly my current solution, I am looking for one without an additional label.

Comment: @Jasco Is changing the format of the input from number to text an option?

Comment: If you mean a change in the SP-list: no, I am not allowed to change the defaults in the list itself, think because the numeric values are needed in other columns for calculation.  However, in PA I tried this = TextFormat.Text & "m²", it doesn't work either! Maybe it could be possible with JSON, but I don't now where and how!

Comment: @Jasco in PA you can change the format type of the input without changing the SP data type. I did this in the second photo of my solution post.
The downside of this would be that users could enter in text values, but you could include some form validation to check if they have an not allow a submission.

Comment: @Jasco what doesn't work? It doesnt display correctly? Or the form doesnt submit correctly? If it's not submitting correctly you can convert the Text back to a Number on submission and strip the last two digits: Value(Left(DataCardValue4.Text, Len(DataCardValue4.Text)-2))

Comment: Sorry, I had missed your last two pics! For your Datacardvalue4, is the SP-LIST (column) declared as Number or Text? Because for me your method doesn't work (List-Column: Number / Powerapps-Datacard: Text. Still shows only 1000

Comment: My SP list column is a number. I added column formatting to display the "m2" suffix. I updated the PowerApps input to be text, and updated the default value. So when you submit the form you strip the suffix off and convert it back to number. 
 Basically treating the value as a simple number and just displaying the suffix after.

Comment: @Jasco your column formatting in the SP list looks good. Double check that your Default value for the text input in the PA form is correct [Parent.Default & "m²"]. Does it work in the editor and not in the SP list form itself? Sometimes a PA publish will take a few moments to update in the SP list form after its published.

Comment: Oh no...I had not updated the list in PA! Works great. Many thanks for your support @JBERG

Comment: @Jasco Yey! Nice, glad it worked out!